# Export all QGIS-project-LayerDefinitions (qlr) using python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I try to export all QGIS-LayerTreeGroups and LayerTreeLayer-definitions (as *.qlr) using following python code (recursive search to search the whole layerTree; the path to save the *.qlr is build from group- and layer-names).

I do not know how to use the "exportLayerDefinition(..,..)".
Python says "[...] AttributeError: 'QgsLayerTreeLayer' object has no attribute 'exportLayerDefinition'" (line 8 +13)

(Using QGIS 2.14 / 2.16)
My Code Sample is

```
def deeperExport(laTrGr, treeName):
    pos = 0
    for child in laTrGr.children():
        if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
            treeName += "/" + child.name()
            deeperExport(child,treeName) 
            path= treeName + ".qlr"
            child.exportLayerDefinition(path, child.children())
            pos = treeName.rfind("/")
            treeName = treeName[0:pos]
        elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
            path = treeName+"/" + child.layerName()+".qlr"
            child.exportLayerDefinition(path, child.children())

#main 
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
print root
treeName = "c:/..."
deeperExport(root, treeName)
```

Comment: From [the doc](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerDefinition.html), `exportLayerDefinition` is a static member of `QgsLayerDefinition`, meaning that you are supposed to call it that way: `QgsLayerDefinition.exportLayerDefinition(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With using the comment of ArMoraer I changed the code as described below - a addidion of missind directories is added to save the whole layer tree as like the qgis-project.

```
import os


def deeperExport(laTrGr, treeName):
    pos = 0
    for child in laTrGr.children():
        if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
            treeName +="/" + child.name()
            deeperExport(child,treeName) 
            path= treeName + ".qlr"
            if not os.path.exists(treeName):
                os.makedirs(treeName)
            QgsLayerDefinition.exportLayerDefinition(path, child.children()) 
            print path
            pos = treeName.rfind("/")
            treeName = treeName[0:pos]
        elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
            path = treeName+"/" + child.layerName()+".qlr"
            print path
            QgsLayerDefinition.exportLayerDefinition(path, child.children()) 

#main 
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
print root
treeName = 'C:/....'
deeperExport(root, treeName)
```

Comment: Very useful. You can except your own answer as the final answer to your question. Just click the hook to the left of your answer!